# Determining stiffness of a beam w/varying moment of inertia

Tags: beam

I need to calculate $K$ or equivalent stiffness of a beam that has a varying $I$ across its length. $I$ has been given to me as a function of $x$, or length.

I have been unable to find a proper equation or set of equations describing how to obtain $K$ for this situation. I've found equations for constant $I$ values across the length of beams. Is there an equation I am simply unaware of, or some general procedure for deriving $K$ for variable $I$ values?

Answer (score 6):

You could insert the variable $I(x)$ into the integral equation for the rotation and the deflection.

First determine your model. Then determine the equation of the moment $M(x)$. Then enter this in the equation of rotation.

rotation: $\theta = \int \frac{M(x)}{E*I(x)}dx $

solve this equation (or let [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) do it for you) , add the relevant boundary conditions (such as $\theta(0) = 0$ for a clamped beam) and then solve

deflection: $\nu = \int \theta dx$

and add the relevant boundary conditions.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is you can't.

The slightly longer answer is you can, but the solution is specific to the adopted cross-section.

The much longer answer will now demonstrate why this is the case by means of an example. In this example, we're just going to take a simple cantilever beam (fixed at $x=0$) of span $L$. The beam will have a variable stiffness $E \cdot I(x)$, since it is a simple rectangular cross-section, with a height that varies (linearly) from $h_0$ at the fixed end to $h_1$ at the free end. The applied load will be a simple concentrated load $P$ at the free end. What is the deflection at the free end?

As @jos already mentioned in their answer, we use the beam equations.

This is an isostatic beam, so the bending moment equation can be trivially obtained as

$$M = P(L-x)$$

this must then be divided by the beam's stiffness and the result must be integrated to obtain the beam's tangent.

$$\theta = \int\limits_0^L\frac{P(L-x)}{E \cdot I(x)}\text{d}x$$

Here we can already see the problem. In ordinary beams we can just remove $EI$ from the integral and go on our merry way. Here, however, $I(x)$ will also need to be integrated.

So, what's the equation for $I(x)$? In this case, it will be

$$I(x) = \frac{b \cdot h(x)^3}{12} = \frac{b \cdot \left(h_0 + \left(h_1-h_0\right)\dfrac{x}{L}\right)^3}{12} = \frac{b \cdot \left(h_0 + \Delta h\dfrac{x}{L}\right)^3}{12}$$

So now we "just" have to find $\theta$.

$$\begin{gather}
\theta = \frac{1}{E}\int\frac{12P(L-x)}{b \cdot \left(h_0 + \Delta h\dfrac{x}{L}\right)^3}\text{d}x \\
\theta = \frac{6PL^3}{Eb\Delta h^2}\left(\frac{-\Delta hL+2\Delta hx+h_0L}{(\Delta hx+h_0L)^2} + C_1\right)
\end{gather}$$

Already getting ugly, right? Now, we just have to integrate this once more to get the deflection.

$$\begin{gather}
\delta = \frac{6PL^3}{Eb\Delta h^2}\int\limits_0^L\left(\frac{-\Delta hL+2\Delta hx+h_0L}{(\Delta hx+h_0L)^2} + C_1\right)\text{d}x \\
\delta = \frac{6P}{Eb\Delta h^2}\left(\dfrac{L(\Delta h+h_0)}{\Delta h(\Delta hx+h_0L)}+\dfrac{2\ln(\Delta hx+h_0L)}{\Delta h}+C_1x+C_2\right)
\end{gather}$$

Now, to find $C_1$ and $C_2$:

$$\begin{gather}
\theta(0) = 0 = \frac{-\Delta hL+h_0L}{(h_0L)^2} + C_1 \\
\therefore C_1 = \frac{\Delta hL-h_0L}{(h_0L)^2} \\
\delta(0) = 0 = \dfrac{L(\Delta h+h_0)}{\Delta hh_0L}+\dfrac{2\ln(h_0L)}{\Delta h}+C_2 \\
\therefore C_2 = -\dfrac{L(\Delta h+h_0)}{\Delta hh_0L}-\dfrac{2\ln(h_0L)}{\Delta h} \\
\end{gather}$$

$$\begin{align}
\therefore \delta = \frac{6P}{Eb\Delta h^2}&\left(\dfrac{L(\Delta h+h_0)}{\Delta h(\Delta hx+h_0L)}+\dfrac{2\ln(\Delta hx+h_0L)}{\Delta h}+ \\
\frac{\Delta hL-h_0L}{(h_0L)^2}x-\dfrac{L(\Delta h+h_0)}{\Delta hh_0L}-\dfrac{2\ln(h_0L)}{\Delta h}\right)
\end{align}
$$

And there you have it. To check my work, I created a beam with $h_0 = 200\ \text{mm}$, $h_1 = 100\ \text{mm}$, $b = 100\ \text{mm}$, $L = 10\ \text{m}$, and $E = 10000\ \text{MPa}$, and applied a load $P = 1\ \text{kN}$ at the end.

I simulated the beam by cutting it into discrete segments, each with a different uniform cross-section. To test the sensitivity, I made two models: one with ten segments and one with twenty. Here are the results:

[image]

Using the equation obtained above, I got 81.78 mm, for an error of 1% compared to the models. Given those are approximations, that looks pretty good.

From this, we can then obviously obtain the stiffness of the beam: $1\ \text{kN}/81.78\ \text{mm} = 12.2\ \text{kN/m}$

So, now that we've gone through all this, what can we learn? Basically, that this is really hard. And the solutions aren't elegant. This was just about the most trivial cross-section ever and things already got messy. I mean, those are logarithms, for crying out loud. What if the section varied both in height **and** width? What if the section didn't vary linearly, but polynomially (or something else)? What if we were dealing with an asymmetrical I-section, with six varying variables ($t_{f,top}$, $b_{f,top}$, $t_{f,bot}$, $b_{f,bot}$, $t_{w}$, $h_{w}$)?

This is why the most common solution when dealing with variable sections is to do as I did: split your beam into discrete segments, each with a different interpolated cross-section. Some professional FEA programs make this easy and some even have variable sections built in, but I don't know how they're implemented.

Comment: Just to alleviate any confusion, should the deflection value be 80.78 mm and not 81.78 mm. I am basing this on your diagram which plots the deflections. Thanks for the work and the explanation.

Comment: @PerryH. The models got 80.78 and 80.86&nbsp;mm. However, the analytical equation I derived via integration of the fundamental beam equation gave 81.78&nbsp;mm. So the "right" answer is 81.78&nbsp;mm, and the diagrams are just to show my derivation is correct (the error is due to the fact that my analytical solution perfectly describes the changing cross-section, while the models use constant sections in each segment).